# How to combine two large character vectors into one data frame?

Tags: r

I have two large character vectors as below:

```
a<- c("Product1_name   Product1_desc       Product1_color","Product2_name   Product2_desc       Product2_color","Product3_name   Product3_desc       Product3_color")

b<- c("16 MAR 2017","15 MAR 2017","20 MAR 2017")
```

How can I combine a and b into one data frame (4 columns) as below:

[image]

Comment: `data.frame(b, do.call(rbind, strsplit(a, '\\s+')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution using the `stringr` and `data.table` package is the following

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

a <- c("Product1_name   Product1_desc       Product1_color","Product2_name   Product2_desc       Product2_color","Product3_name   Product3_desc       Product3_color")
b <- c("16 MAR 2017","15 MAR 2017","20 MAR 2017")

# remove multiple consecutive spaces from a
a <- str_replace_all(a, "( )+", " ")

# create data table
dt <- data.table(
  date = b,
  product_tmp = a
)

# split temporary product column in three columns
dt[, c("product_name", "product_desc", "product_color") := tstrsplit(product_tmp, " ")]

# remove temporary product column
dt[, product_tmp := NULL]

# show data table
dt
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` to split the 'a' into three columns and `cbind` with 'b'

```
cbind(b, read.table(text=a, header=FALSE))
```